# The value is invalid yet should it is a valid input value

Tags: c#, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm creating a webpage using MVC 5, Visual Studio, C#.

In my view I have a remark page which the user is allowed to make a remark in a text box and click "save" to save the remark in a database. However, it is saying that the value of the remark is invalid when it shouldn't be.

The error is

> The value 'Testing Remark' is invalid

yet it should be valid

In my model, I have a class called Recall, which has a

```
public string Remark {get; set;}
```

In the view I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Remark, htmlAttributes: new {@class ="control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remark, 5, 50, new { @class = "text-danger"})
    @Html.validationMessageFor(model => model.Remark, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

In the controller
....
not putting the controller code here since it should have nothing to do with the error I'm getting.

Comment: First, `validationMessageFor` should have an uppercase `V`.  Second, your error says `Testing Remark`, but you haven't shown any `DisplayAttribute`s on your model property.  You should provide all relevant code.

Comment: You are showing a Validation message but are not including the validation logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use data type MultilineText if you are using a TextArea:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Remark { get; set; }
```

Or just change the TextAreaFor to a TextBoxFor if you don't need multi line text:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Remark, new { @class = "text-danger"})
```

Comment: I took that out to see the effect and I still am getting the "The value 'Testing Remark' is invalid" error with [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] and without it

Comment: I would have to retype everything out its on a DEV computer with no internet access, Would you have any suggestions as to why it would say invalid type when it is declared as a string and the input is text

Comment: Just post the data annotations for the Remark property on your view model. You must have some as you are using LabelFor and ValidationMessageFor.